# React Native - will image require always convert to the same integer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, assets, require

In my react native app that involves cryptocurrency, I have a global redux state called `coinImageUrls` with this structure:

```
coinImageUrls = {
  BTC: 'https://coin-image-url/btc.png',
  ETH: 'https://coin-image-url/eth.png',
  ABC: 31,
}
```

This object is populated when I do `Image.prefetch` to cache the remote images. If the image url is valid, I will store the url string as it is. However if the `prefetch` fails due to invalid image url, I will use a local fallback image with `require`. The gist of the code is something like this: (not the original code obviously, since `coinImageUrls` is in redux)

```
Image.prefetch(imageLink)
  .then(() => {
    coinImageUrls[coinSymbol] = imageLink
  })
  .catch(() => {
    coinImageUrls[coinSymbol] = require('../assets/fallback-image.png')
  })
```

Lastly, the images are loaded by checking whether it's a string or integer.

```
typeof coinImageUrls[coinSymbol] === 'string'
  ? <Image source={{uri: coinImageUrls[coinSymbol]}} />
  : <Image source={coinImageUrls[coinSymbol]} />
```

The key point here is, the entire prefetching will only happen *ONCE* for each coin symbol. That means the moment coin ABC was assigned with 31 (converted from `require`), it will never change.

So my question is, will the number 31 ever change? If it does is it possible to make sure `require` always convert to same integer? Is this even an issue in production environment?